# Button Flickering onHover in React

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, onhover, react-button

I have 2 Components "TableCard" et "TableGrouping". I have a component inside "TableCard" called "Grouping".

When I hover the button with my mouse it is flickering/flashing on my screen. The 2 components are separated in 2 files because I need to modify the content of "TableGrouping" in "TableCard" (when I put directly the content of grouping into "TableGrouping" it's working fine but it's not my objective.

Here is my code:

```
export function TableGrouping(props) {
  return (
    <div className="form">
      <div className="row align-items-center form-group-actions margin-top-20 margin-bottom-20">
        <div className="col-xl-12">
          <div className="form-group form-group-inline">
            <div className="form-label form-label-no-wrap">
              {props.children}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
export function TableCard() {
  const Grouping = () => {
    function BtnSupprimer(props) {
      return <Button>test</Button>;
    }

    return (
      <>
        <BtnSupprimer/>
      </>
    );
  };
return (
   <TableGrouping>
     <Grouping />
   </TableGrouping>
  );
}
```

Link of what it's doing : [here](https://youtu.be/5991a_76r0M)

Do some of you have an Idea ? Thank you :)

Comment: Think you could create a *running* codesandbox that reproduces the issue and link it in your question, something we can see and live debug in?

Comment: I don't know how to to this so I made this: [youtube video of the problem](https://youtu.be/5991a_76r0M)

Comment: [codesnadbox](https://codesandbox.io/) it's an online IDE, basically a clone of Vscode. You can copy the relevant files and create quick demos. Can you at least include a more [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example? The button you highlight in the video appears to be a different button, "renommer".

Comment: it's not the same button but it does the same thing with all these 4 buttons. I did copy the part on codesandbox but it's working perfectly :( I will modify the code a little bit

Comment: Ok, feel free to (at) me when you've something we can look at.